# EOFException when reading file from storage (cn1)

Tags: codenameone

I have made an externalizable object - User. It works fine when writing to and reading it from storage except if I exit the app and reopen it. Then this error occurs:

> java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)   at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)     at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)     at
>   com.codename1.io.Util.readUTF(Util.java:962)

I have registered the class as follows in the stateMachine:

```
@Override
    protected void initVars(Resources res) {
        Util.register("User", User.class);
}
```

This is the class:

```
package userclasses;

import com.codename1.io.Externalizable;
import com.codename1.io.Util;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class User implements Externalizable {

    private static final int VERSION = 1;

    public int userID;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String firstname;
    public String surname;
    public String email;
    public Date registerDate;
    public boolean paidUser;
    public double runStep;
    public double walkStep;



    public User(){
    }

    @Override
    public int getVersion() {
        return VERSION;

    }

    @Override
    public void externalize(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.write(userID);
        Util.writeUTF(username, out);
        Util.writeUTF(password, out);
        Util.writeUTF(firstname, out);
        Util.writeUTF(surname, out);
        Util.writeUTF(email, out);
        out.writeLong(registerDate.getTime());
        out.writeBoolean(paidUser);
        out.writeDouble(runStep);
        out.writeDouble(walkStep);

    }

    @Override
    public void internalize(int version, DataInputStream in) throws      IOException {
        userID = in.readInt();
        username = Util.readUTF(in);
        password = Util.readUTF(in);
        firstname = Util.readUTF(in);
        surname = Util.readUTF(in);
        email = Util.readUTF(in);
        registerDate = new Date(in.readLong());
        paidUser = in.readBoolean();
        runStep = in.readDouble();
        walkStep = in.readDouble();

    }

    @Override
    public String getObjectId() {
        return "User";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
out.write(userID);
```

With:

```
out.writeInt(userID);
```

The default write method is the equivalent of `writeByte`.

Comment: My pleasure. FYI when an answer is correct you need to accept it with the checkmark next to the answer. An upvote is also polite for good answers. Note that you get additional points too when accepting answers which helps you access more functionality in stackoverflow and improves the site experience.